# Using MinGW to compile a SFML project

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

Okay, so I have a C++ project that uses SFML, and I want to be able to compile it from the CMD using MinGW.  I have it so I can compile.cpp's, however, I just need to know what more I have to do in order for it to work with SFML.  I tried compiling it with CodeBlocks and MinGW, and it works fine, until I try to run it, at which point it tells me that sfml-system.dll is missing from my computer.  Does this mean I installed it incorrectly?  I followed the CodeBlocks installation down to the letter, from what I could tell...  I put the include\SFML in the include\ of MinGW, and I put all the *.a's from lib\ into the \lib of MinGW as well.
Thank you for the help you can give!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so if it builds well and links with the `sfml-system.dll` at link time then there is no real problem. All you need to do is copy the `sfml-system.dll` (or make a link to it) in the directory, where the built `.exe` file is. That would make the `.exe` find the required library.

Comment: Oops...  I forgot to update the question last night...  I found sfml-system.dll and put that with the directory, but now it can't find something called libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll...  I've searched my entire computer for it, and it is nowhere to be found.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is part of the MingW compiler libraries. It should be at the place, where MingW is installed. Somewhere in its sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

*libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll* is just inside **bin** folder, on latest [MinGW releases](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-7.3.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0.7z/download).

Copy to **.exe** folder, it should run.