# How to compile SFML with MinGW?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, sfml

I have a simple file "main.cpp" seen below. I also have all the sfml 2.1 libraries under "C:\SFML-2.1\". My question is: What are the commands to compile, link, and run this project? I'm very comfortable using g++ to compile projects from the command line, but have never done so with any external libraries (such as sfml) before. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do it from the command line I suggest you get familiar with some type of build tool like [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/).

Comment: I considered doing it with make, do you by chance know where a viable makefile for sfml 2.1 might reside so I can utilize it?

Comment: have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263359/using-mingw-to-compile-a-sfml-project

Comment: Yes, I saw that question before posting this one and I don't have any of the .a library files, only the files that come when downloaded from sfml.org. I also am not having the same issue as him because I don't even know how to compile my simple program with sfml libraries recognized.

Comment: SFML includes the necessary files to build with cmake.

Answer (score 5):

## Quick Answer

```
g++ -c main.cpp -IC:\SFML-2.1\include -DSFML_STATIC

g++ main.o -o main -LC:\SFML-2.1\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32

main
```

---

## Long Answer

I'll show you how to either link the project statically or dynamically. It doesn't matter which one you chose to do if you are running the project on your computer, but if you want to send the executable file to another device, choose static linking.

**Compile Project**

First, compile, but not link, your project using the `-c` flag. Make sure to include the SFML header files using the `-I` prefix.

If you are going to statically link SFML, include `SFML_STATIC` using the `-D` flag.

```c
// dynamic linking
g++ -c main.cpp -IC:\SFML-2.1\include

// static linking
g++ -c main.cpp -IC:\SFML-2.1\include -DSFML_STATIC
```

**Link Project**

Now you have to link the SFML libraries. To link a library, use the `-l` prefix. For convenience, link the ones you're most likely to use: `-lsfml-graphics`, `-lsfml-window`, and `-ssfml-system`.

If you are statically linking, use a `-s` prefix on the libraries: `-lsfml-graphics-s`, `-lsfml-window-s`, and `-lsfml-system-s`.

You also have to link certain dependencies for the libraries. That's the `opengl32`, `winmm`, and `gdi32` libraries. Again, use the prefix `-l` to link the libraries (you don't need the `-s` suffix on these libraries even if you are statically linking it).

```c
// dynamic linking
g++ main.o -o main -LC:\SFML-2.1\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32

// static linking
g++ main.o -o main -LC:\SFML-2.1\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
```

**Run Project**

And lastly, just type the name of the executable file in the command line:

```
main
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 3):

Copy the `SFML` folder present at say `Downloads\SFML-2.5.1\include\` to `mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\10.3.0\include\` this should compile your `main.cpp` using command

`g++ main.cpp -c -o main.o`

For linking, copy all the `.a` files present at `SFML-2.5.1\lib` to `msys64\mingw64\lib` where all the different linkers are present, this should link your object file, use command

`g++ main.o -o main.exe -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32`

Then to run the exe file, you need to copy the `.dll` files, for that, copy all the files inside `SFML-2.5.1\bin` to `mingw64\bin`, then just open the .exe file, it should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can add SFML to path of your compiler or use `g++ -I path/SFML`